# BigQuery Table saying duplicate column

Tags: google-bigquery, google-ads-api, google-ad-manager

We have our google ads data updating with our BigQuery database. The SearchQueryStats table has become un-query-able because of a 'Duplicate column' error. I'm not search on that column, nor can I see it duplicated in name within the schema

Query I'm using

```
SELECT * FROM `database.SearchQueryStats` LIMIT 1000
```

I get this error

'Duplicate column name 'QueryMatchTypeWithVariant' in definition of view'

When I look at the table scheme there is a QueryMatchTypeWithVariant field and a QueryMatchTypeWithVariant_1 field.

Even when I run

```
SELECT campaignID, creativeID FROM `database.SearchQueryStats` LIMIT 1000
```

I'll get the same error despite not searching on the error column.